GPS-Denied Drone Navigation
So, basically, do you guys know how can a GPS-Denied visual navigation system for drones work? Like I’ve read a bunch of papers on this topic, my concept is simple: create a system that will snap a photo from a drone and will compare that photo with available satellite imagery.
My question is this: Do you think MI (Mutual Information) method is better than, let’s say, HOG? Why?
